# Writing to text file formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have an assignment to make a simple task manager/todo list. This code block is just the part of the program that handles login, new username and password registration. When the user registers that input is written to a text file called `user.txt`.

Whenever it writes to the text file, it writes like this:`(['admin', 'adm1n'])`
instead, it should write it like this:`admin, adm1n`

```
user_file = open("user.txt","r+")
login = False

while login == False:
new = input("Are you a new user? Y/N:\n").lower()

if new == "y":
    print("Please register a new username and password:\n")
    new_user1 = input("Please enter a new username:\n").split()
    new_pass1 = input("Please enter a new password:\n").split()
    new_user2 = input("Please confirm your username:\n").split()
    new_pass2 = input("Please confirm your password:\n").split()
    user_pass1 = new_user1 , new_pass1
    user_pass2 = new_user2 , new_pass2
    if user_pass1 == user_pass2:
        user_file.write(f"{user_pass2},")
        user_file.seek(0)
    break

elif new == "n":
    username = input("Enter your username:\n")
    password = input("Enter your password:\n")
    valid_user = username
    valid_password = password
    
for line in user_file:
    valid_user, valid_password = line.split(", ")
    if username == valid_user and password == valid_password:
        login = True

if login == False:
    print("Incorrect details! Please enter a valid username and password")
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's something small.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a sequence to be printed in a non-standard way, you'll need to tell `print` what that way is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback everyone.

I managed to get it figured out. I added an index to it to print the string and it worked just fine.

```
    user_pass2 = new_user2 , new_pass2
    if user_pass1 == user_pass2:
        #Writes username and password to text file in format requested.
        user_file.write(f'\n{user_pass2[0]}, {user_pass2[1]}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are making a tuple there. Instead, you should create a string. Here is the corrected version of your code

```
    user_pass1 = new_user1 + ',' + new_pass1
    user_pass2 = new_user2 + ',' + new_pass2
    if user_pass1 == user_pass2:
        user_file.write(f"{user_pass2},")
        user_file.seek(0)
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's introduced an new error, `can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`.

I'll keep trying

Comment: you should remove the split() from the inputs